# yq returns null but not read in condition if value is null

Tags: bash, yq

I have a command that takes a field in a YAML file and will execute some commands if the returned value is null. I am using this implementation https://github.com/kislyuk/yq .

```
TAG="$(yq -y '.pod.image.imageTag' "${VALUES_FILE}")"
if [ "${TAG}" = null ]; then
        echo "no tag is found..."
else
        echo "Tag is ${TAG}..."
fi
```

but I keep getting `'Tag is null'`. I tried with 'null' and "null" but same result...

Comment: Please follow the [mre] guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Using [yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

On my computer the content of the tag is `null\n...`, not `null`.
To get rid of the trailing dashes use `yq` without the option `-y`.
Add the option `-r` for raw output.

```bash
INPUT='
pod:
  image:
    imageTag: moonwalk
'

TAG=$(yq -r '.pod.image.imageTag' <<< "$INPUT")
if [ $TAG == null ]; then
  echo "no tag is found"
else
  echo "Tag is $TAG"
fi
```

**Output**

```
Tag is moonwalk
```

---

```bash
INPUT='
pod:
  image:
    imageTag:
'

# same code as above
```

**Output**

```
no tag is found
```

Comment: I don't want to use the exit code because I'm using this script in a pipeline and it will exit and stop if I do this with -e.

Comment: ok ... I adopted my answer.

Comment: `a && b || c` is **not** identical to `if a; then b; else c; fi`. See [BashPitfalls #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3).

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Thank you ... I bookmarked the page with the pitfalls and changed it in my answer

Comment: @joe1531, `set -e` won't stop your script if the code that fails is in an `if`. So: `if tag=$(...); then ...`

Comment: @joe1531, that said, I advise against using `set -e`; see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises -- explicit error handling (`foo || return`, `foo || exit`, etc) is much more predictable.